Tailwind css site not working on github pages
I made the FB login page clone using Tailwind CSS and it works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it to GitHub pages it shows me errors.
It worked well on Netlify but it's giving errors on GitHub pages
here is the link
[

Your GitHub Pages site is at the URL https://gayatri-tech.github.io/FbLoginPage, in a subpath from the main host name, https://gayatri-tech.github.io/.
In index.html, the CSS is referenced with the value /src/output.css which resolve to https://gayatri-tech.github.io/src/output.css. However, the file from your repository would be located at https://gayatri-tech.github.io/FbLoginPage/src/output.css, hence the 404 not found error.
To resolve this, you could consider making the path reference relative by removing the first slash (/):
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/output.css" />

The same resolution for the favicon reference:
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="fb_icon.png" />


Could you please elaborate on why it was causing errors?

In index.html, the CSS is referenced with the value /src/output.css which resolves to https://gayatri-tech.github.io/src/output.css. However, the file from your repository would be located at https://gayatri-tech.github.io/FbLoginPage/src/output.css, hence the 404 not found error. Changing the path to without the first slash means the resolved path would be the correct https://gayatri-tech.github.io/FbLoginPage/src/output.css.

Okay, but my question is about the use of slash here. Why the use of slash referred to the wrong URL

The beginning slash has special meaning, whereby it references the "root". Thus the value /src/output.css resolves to https://gayatri-tech.github.io/src/output.css where / means https://gayatri-tech.github.io/. However, the file from your repository would be located at https://gayatri-tech.github.io/FbLoginPage/src/output.css. Hence the /-prefixed path reference is wrong.

Can you try changing your pathing for these lines?
index.html file
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/fb_icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/output.css" />

TO
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="fb_icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/output.css" />

package.json
"build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch"

TO
"build": "npx tailwindcss -i src/input.css -o src/output.css --watch"


It worked well but it's not working on Vercel. If anyone knows please answer it. The GitHub link is also mentioned in my question.
